# Dynamics 365 Web API: GetAsync record without OData-EntityId

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm new to the Dynamics 365 Web API and I'm trying some things out.
I followed and used the BasicOperations C# application with success.

Now I would like to perform an HTTP GET method to get an account/contact record and then update it with new values.

The problem is that I can't seem to get the record without using the OData-EntityId. Is it even possible to do so? All the examples start with creating an entity and then using the ID to perform update/delete/get methods.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that. Basically you want to filter another field other than Primary key field.

For example the below code will retrieve all the records where `new_test` attribute value is 12.

```
var response = httpClient.GetAsync("[Organization URI] api/data/v9.0/new_test?$select=new_testid,new_amount,new_caseid,new_email&$filter=new_test eq '12'",
```

[Read more](http://www.mscrm.com/2018/01/retrieve-multiple-entity-record-in.html?m=1)

Comment: It worked with the filter. But where can I find the possible select values? Can I find that in Dynamics 365?

Comment: @Niels I recommend you to use CRM Rest Builder to compose queries.. download the solution & import in org to use it right away https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder